# Adding accessory button on user location callout

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkuserlocation

I'm making a clickable placemark. I set the title of the placemark. Title is adress. I want If you click on that adress It will push to another View to Show Adress Number,City,Country etc. I Tried this code. But It haven't UIButton in application in placemark, why?

**EDIT:** If I put breakpoint to func  calloutAccessoryControlTapped it isn't crashing.

```
func mapView(Mapa: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        //return nil so map view draws "blue dot" for standard user location
        return nil
    }

    var pin = "pin"

    var view = Mapa.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(pin) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if view == nil {
        view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: pin)
        view!.canShowCallout = true
        view!.animatesDrop = true
        var arrowButton = UIButton()
        view!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.buttonWithType(.DetailDisclosure) as! UIButton
    } else {
        view!.annotation = annotation
    }
    return view
}

func mapView(Mapa: MKMapView!, annotation: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    if control == annotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        println("Pressed!")
    }
}
```

Whole code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var Mapa: MKMapView!
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var detail: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()



        Mapa.delegate = self
        Mapa.mapType = MKMapType.Standard
        Mapa.showsUserLocation = true


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }



    //--- Find Address of Current Location ---//

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)
    {
        //--- CLGeocode to get address of current location ---//
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in
            let spanX = 0.007
            let spanY = 0.007
            var newRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: self.Mapa.userLocation.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(spanX, spanY))
            self.Mapa.setRegion(newRegion, animated: true)


            if (error != nil)
            {
                println("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if placemarks.count > 0
            {
                let pm = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
                self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
            }
            else
            {
                println("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
            }
        })

    }


    func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark?)
    {
        if let Placemark = placemark
        {
            //Stop updating kvôli vydrži baterke
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            let location = self.locationManager.location
            var latitude: Double = location.coordinate.latitude
            var longitude: Double = location.coordinate.longitude
            let adresa = (Placemark.thoroughfare != nil) ? Placemark.thoroughfare : "Ulica: "
            let cislo = (Placemark.subThoroughfare != nil) ? Placemark.subThoroughfare : "Číslo ulice:"
            let mesto = (Placemark.locality != nil) ? Placemark.locality : "Mesto: "
            let stat = (Placemark.country != nil) ? Placemark.country : "Štát: "




            var coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D = placemark!.location.coordinate
            let theLocation: MKUserLocation = Mapa.userLocation
            theLocation.title = adresa




            println("GPS Súradnice :: \(latitude), \(longitude)")
            println(mesto)
            println(adresa)
            println(cislo)
            println(stat)

        }

    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!)
    {
        println("Chyba pri aktualizovaní lokácie " + error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func mapView(Mapa: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            //return nil so map view draws "blue dot" for standard user location
            return nil
        }

        var pin = "pin"

        var view = Mapa.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(pin) as? MKPinAnnotationView
        if view == nil {
            view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: pin)
            view!.canShowCallout = true
            view!.animatesDrop = true
            var arrowButton = UIButton()
            view!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.buttonWithType(.DetailDisclosure) as! UIButton
        } else {
            view!.annotation = annotation
        }
        return view
    }

    func mapView(Mapa: MKMapView!, annotation: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

        if control == annotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
            println("Pressed!")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to put a button on the callout of the user location (blue dot) or on your own pin?

Comment: I want to put a button on the blue dot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to put an accessory button on the callout of the blue dot (user location).

In the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method, you do have code that creates an annotation view and sets the `rightCalloutAccessoryView` but at the top of the method there is this code:

```
func mapView(Mapa: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        //return nil so map view draws "blue dot" for standard user location
        return nil
    }
```

The map's user location annotation is of type `MKUserLocation` so when the map view calls `viewForAnnotation` for it, this code returns `nil` for it which the map view interprets as "display the default view and callout for this annotation".  The default callout only shows a title and subtitle.

The code that creates a custom view and sets `rightCalloutAccessoryView` never executes.

To set a `rightCalloutAccessoryView`, you need a reference to the actual annotation *view* object.

You could remove that `return nil` for the `MKUserLocation` but then you'll get a standard pin instead of an animated blue dot.

You can't create your own instance of the animated blue dot view because that class is private.

So you can't create or get access to the user location annotation view in the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method.

A place where you can reliably get access to the actual user location annotation view is in the `didAddAnnotationViews` delegate method.  I suggest this method because it means an annotation view has actually been created and is on the screen.

In this method, call the map view's `viewForAnnotation` instance method and pass it its `userLocation` annotation and then set the view's `rightCalloutAccessoryView`:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didAddAnnotationViews views: [AnyObject]!) {
    if let ulav = mapView.viewForAnnotation(mapView.userLocation) {
        ulav.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.buttonWithType(.DetailDisclosure) as! UIButton
    }
}
```

---

Unrelated to the callout button not appearing but:
Your `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method is named wrong and will not get called when the button is tapped.

Your method is named `mapView(annotation:calloutAccessoryControlTapped)`.

The `annotation` parameter must be named `annotationView` and even though naming the map view parameter `Mapa` will work, I suggest sticking to the signature given in the documentation so the revised method would be:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!) {
    if control == annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        println("Pressed!")
    }
}
```